# Split vocal from piano in a very simple song

Tags: osx, audio, music, music-production

I have a very simple song which has only a vocal and a piano sound. I want to remove the piano sound, and indeed, only get the vocal. According to this link: [How to Isolate Vocals in Audacity](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s2StlHv-D8E&feature=youtu.be), there is an option in `Audacity` for this matter. But actually, it is just a noise reduction, and it cannot remove the piano sound as I expected. Considering that the song is very simple and there are no instruments except a piano in this song, is there a software which can remove the piano sound or at least reduce the piano volume as much as possible?

Comment: On what OS should the software run, and how much would you be willing to invest if it comes to paid software?

Comment: macOS, cost does not matter although I prefer the free one:) @Izzy

Answer (score 1):

Really, the only app that comes anywhere close *[if the phase flip trick doesn't work, which it usually doesn't]* is Izotope's [Music Rebalance](https://www.izotope.com/en/products/rx/features/music-rebalance.html)

It is only available as part of a larger package & starts at $399

Even at that price it isn't perfect. It works on some sources better than others. A demo of the full [RX7 suite](https://www.izotope.com/en/products/rx.html) is available, so you can at least try it before committing.